# Xampp 1.8.3-4 server issue with FTP and MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

It's been two days I'm Googling to find a solution and not successful as of now. I'm trying to get Xampp 1.3.8-4 working properly in my Mac Maverics.

Out of the 3 green indicators in the 'Manage Servers' window only Apache Web Server is running and trying hard to get MySql database and proFTPD running with no luck.

This has been working fine and only change I've done is installed WordPress and added a few themes if that helps.

Application logs says below;

```
Starting all servers...
Starting MySQL Database...

Starting ProFTPD...
Checking syntax of configuration file
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/proftpd/scripts/ctl.sh : proftpd started
Starting MySQL Database...

Stopping all servers...
Stopping Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd stopped
Restarting all servers...
Starting MySQL Database...

Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
Starting ProFTPD...
Checking syntax of configuration file
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/proftpd/scripts/ctl.sh : proftpd started
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the you are trying to run two Apache servers at the same time. I got the same problem on my Mac running Xampp 1.8.3-4 server and i got my Apple version of Apache server already running. If you open your browser and type 'localhost' and it say 'It Works', means the the apple version of Apache server is already running.

To stop the Apple version of Apache server:

In OSX 10.7 and earlier, you could start and stop the Apache Web Server in Control Panel, by choosing "Sharing" and then unchecking the "Web Sharing" checkbox. As of 10.8 this option is no longer in the control panel.

To disable Apple's version of Apache in current versions of OS X, open a Terminal window and type this command:

sudo apachectl stop

You will need to type your system password when prompted, then you should be able to start the XAMPP version of Apache.

Reference:
https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=68351